# fancyvrb and \overfullrule

Tags: fancyvrb

I know I can use `\overfullrule=5pt` to get overfull lines marked with a black marker, but using the `Verbatim` environment from the `fancyvrb` package the overfull lines are not marked. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\overfullrule=5pt

\begin{document}
\mbox{Overfull line marked without using the Verbatim environment from the fancyvrn package.}

\begin{Verbatim}
Overfull line not marked using the Verbatim environment from the fancyvrb package.
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Note: I know I can use the `BVervatim` environment to mark the overfull lines, but it changes all the code layout in my document.

Is it possible to use the `Verbatim` environment and to get the overfull lines marked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\overfullrule=5pt
\makeatletter

\let\oldFancyVerbFormatLine\FancyVerbFormatLine
\def\FancyVerbFormatLine#1{%
\setbox0\hbox{\oldFancyVerbFormatLine{#1}}%
\ifdim\wd0>\textwidth
\hbox{\box\z@\vrule\@width\overfullrule}%
\else
\box\z@
\fi} 
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\mbox{Overfull line marked without using the Verbatim environment from the fancyvrn package.}


\begin{Verbatim}
Overfull line not marked using the Verbatim environment from the fancyvrb package.
short line
Overfull line not marked using the Verbatim environment from the fancyvrb package.
\end{Verbatim}



\end{document}
```